# Why does the `hjust` parameter have no effect on the position of the text in ggplotly?

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, position, geom-text

I want the labels `Country1` and `Country2` to be on the left of the point, but they are in the middle.
I set `hjust = 0` but it does not work.

```r
df <- structure(list(Epreuve = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), levels = "CE", class = "factor"),     Country = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L,     1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), levels = c("Country1",     "Country2"), class = "factor"), Month = structure(c(18779,     18779, 18809, 18809, 18840, 18871, 18871, 18901, 18901, 18932,     18962, 18962, 18993, 19024, 19024, 19052, 19083, 19113, 19144,     19144), class = "Date"), moyenn_gliss = c(55, 62, 47.5, 68.5,     44.6666666666667, 36, 45.6666666666667, 38, 25, 41.6666666666667,     48.6666666666667, 16.6666666666667, 52, 45.6666666666667,     25, 34, 23.3333333333333, 17.6666666666667, 25.3333333333333,     51.6666666666667), nb_total = c(250L, 38L, 250L, 38L, 250L,     250L, 38L, 250L, 38L, 250L, 250L, 38L, 250L, 250L, 38L, 250L,     250L, 250L, 250L, 38L), grp = c(4L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L,     4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

library(tidyverse); library(plotly)
p <- df %>% 
  mutate(label = ifelse(Month == max(Month), paste(Country, Epreuve), NA)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, moyenn_gliss, color = interaction(Country, Epreuve, drop = T, sep = " "))) + 
  geom_point(aes(size =  size_pt <<- grp)) + 
  geom_line(aes(size = size_pt * 0.7)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = label, y = moyenn_gliss), hjust = 0, vjust = 0.5, size = 3) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = unique(df$Month), date_labels="%b %y") +
  theme(legend.position="none") 

p %>% ggplotly()
```

[image]

Comment: hjust=0 will align to the left of the datapoint. But It does not account for the size of the geom_point. Why the hjust is not respected by `ggplotly` is a different issue. Maybe a bug?

Comment: Yes, the problem comes from `ggplotly`, since it works with a plain `ggplot`

Answer (score 1):

You could use the function `style` from `plotly` with `textposition = "left"` like this:

```
library(tidyverse); library(plotly)
p <- df %>% 
  mutate(label = ifelse(Month == max(Month), paste(Country, Epreuve), NA)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Month, moyenn_gliss, color = interaction(Country, Epreuve, drop = T, sep = " "))) + 
  geom_point(aes(size =  size_pt <<- grp)) + 
  geom_line(aes(size = size_pt * 0.7)) + 
  geom_text(aes(label = label, y = moyenn_gliss), hjust = 0, vjust = 0.5, size = 3) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = unique(df$Month), date_labels="%b %y") +
  theme(legend.position="none") 

p %>% ggplotly() %>% style(textposition = "left")
```

Output:

[image]

It still seems to be an [issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/issues/769).

Comment: I want it on the right in fact, but I will try this